# Eigen compile configuration without CUDA support

Tags: eigen

I'm just trying to compile Eigen library at version 3.3.3 for armv7-a with NEON enabled. CMake reports me continuosly error because it cannot find a alid toolchain for CUDA. I don't want it enabled!

The question so is: How to compile without enabling CUDA? I don't want it!

Comment: Can you post your CMakeLists file(s)?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AimV30f9kpMihUuh6v91n9VqZAHP

Comment: @Bna'Marco, I am facing the same issue, did you manage to compile it?

Comment: I've downgraded to the previous version... 3.2.10

Answer (score 0):

On 3.2.3 (latest stable as of posting), simply leaving `CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR` as `CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND` results in a valid configuration with CUDA disabled (you might get warnings but the project will still be generated).

Since 3.3.3 is unstable, perhaps there is a bug in the cmake procedure which means that it does not automatically recover if CUDA is not found.

That said, Eigen is a header-only library, and therefore you don't actually need to build it (just include it).